# Converting list to a select box for below 480px including its anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to implement a custom select box like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4y2wD/). How can I convert by below code to that. Here is my current working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh4y426f/)

```html
     
<body>
<div class="i-home-left">

 <ul id="make-select-box">
   <li><a href="#i-bc"> 1 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#i-st"> 2 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#i-mm"> 3 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#i-cc"> 4 </a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div id="i-bc">some content here </div>
<div id="i-st">some content here </div>
<div id="i-mm">some content here </div>
<div id="i-cc">some content here </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh4y426f/)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow here is js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vh4y426f/

Comment: This is quite useful for me but i need links in this.  http://jsfiddle.net/4y2wD/

Comment: yesterday i solved this issue

Comment: can you please share with me. This will help me alot. Thanks in Advance

Comment: shared let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Improve title's readability

Comment: @MauroPorrasP yes updated

Comment: Why you are not using the html select tag?

Comment: @ Nitheesh Right question, I want to convert a list to select box for below 480px width. I will update title. Thank you for this question

Answer (score 1):

For that you can do this, Here it will show list on large screen and in case of small screen it will toggle it to select box.

```
  <ul id="make-select-box">
     <li><a href="#i-bc"> 1 </a></li>
     <li><a href="#i-st"> 2 </a></li>
     <li><a href="#i-mm"> 3 </a></li>
     <li><a href="#i-cc"> 4 </a></li>
  </ul>

  <select class="toggle-view">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
```

In CSS

```
   .toggle-view {
      display : block;
    }
   #make-select-box {
       display : none;
    }

   @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     .toggle-view {
         display : none;
      }
     #make-select-box {
         display : block;
      }
    }
```

Or if you want to do this by javascript(dynamically), then you can use below code,

```
   var sel = $('<select id="tesing2"/>');
   onResize = function() {
   if($(window).width() < 480) {
       $('#make-select-box li').each(function(){
       sel.append('<option value='$(this).children('a').attr('href')'>'+this.innerHTML+'</option>')
        })
       $('#make-select-box').replaceWith(sel);
    } 
    $('select').on('change', function() {
     var url = this.value;
     window.location = this.value;
    })

  }

  $(document).ready(onResize)
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: When option selected its not moving to particular id in that same page.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I tried this code previously. Its converting a li to select box with value, but i need something like onselect  event and goto somewhere etc, if you can solve this might be very appreciable.

Comment: @ImmranMohammed Edited my javascript code for you, you can check now, also you can try other options in place of window.location to redirect to you url.

Comment: This is what i am looking for, but its not converting li to select box. I have tried this and googled alot. but no use. I can't find whats wrong in this code. can you please help me to find whether there is any syntax errors or any ... anyway Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: can you please create a plunker with the code you tried ?

Comment: I cant provide proper css due to its compressed and comes from various parts.                                                                https://plnkr.co/edit/CI4De1jUmQgrxZT1ymVj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<span id='selected_val'></span>
<ul id="make-select-box" >
   <li><a href="#i-bc" onClick='toggleDropDown(1)'> 1 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#i-st" onClick='toggleDropDown(2)'> 2 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#i-mm" onClick='toggleDropDown(3)'> 3 </a></li>
   <li><a href="#i-cc" onClick='toggleDropDown(4)'> 4 </a></li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
var selectval;
function renderDropDown(){
  $('#make-select-box').css('display', 'none');
  if(selectVal == undefined){
    document.getElementById('selected_val').innerHTML = 1;
  }
}
renderDropDown()
```

Toggle Dropdown

```
var selectval
function toggleDropDown(arg){
  selectVal = arg;
  document.getElementById('selected_val').innerHTML = arg;
  $('#make-select-box').toggle();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but i want to convert a ul into select box from $(window).width() < 480 , i think onclick event within a tag gives me different results. Once again thanks for your response.

Comment: can you please check these fiddles.Current fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vh4y426f/ and quite useful fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4y2wD/

Comment: You need to design ul accordingly as select box but i told you about the functional implementation